# ¿Como puedo listar los ficheros con antigüedad mayor a 10 minutos de un directorio y luego contarlos en Python?

Tags: python, lista, windows

Estoy intentando de listar los ficheros de un directorio windows a través de python con antigüedad mayor a 10 minutos y no soy capaz a alguien puede ayudarme?

Esto es lo que estaba ejecutando:

`files=os.system(     'powershell.exe (Get-ChildItem -path "C:\Users\Jose Antonio\Documents") | where {$_.Lastwritetime -lt (date).addminutes(-10)}'`

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo?

Comment: Si, a través de os.system intentando ejecutar powershell pero tampoco me funciona:

`files=os.system(
    'powershell.exe (Get-ChildItem -path "C:\Users\Jose Antonio\Documents") | where {$_.Lastwritetime -lt (date).addminutes(-10)}'`

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: El código, los errores, los problemas, van EN la pregunta. No pongas a la gente a adivinar, así nadie te va a sugerir lo que te ha fallado. De paso, puede que el problema en tu aproximación sea solucionable. Ve a [edit] tu pregunta y pon allí lo que has intentado; acá en los comentarios el código es infumable (y por todo lo anterior, tu pregunta está cerca de ser cerrada)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La biblioteca `pathlib` te da parte de las herramientas necesarias, no necesitas llamar a shells externos. `pathlib` te permite iterar por todos los contenidos de un directorio con:

```
pathlib.Path(directorio).iterdir()
```

Cada elemento de la iteración es un objeto de tipo `Path` que es una representación genérica de un fichero en el sistema de archivos. Estos objetos tienen el método `.stat()` que te permite acceder a aspectos como la fecha en que fueron creados o modificados por última vez. En concreto `.stat().st_mtime` te dan el instante de la última modificación (en forma de timestamp, o contador de segundos desde una fecha origen).

El módulo `time` te da el resto de lo que necesitas, en concreto `time.time()` te da el timestamp actual. Restando a este timestamp el que obtuviste antes sabes cuántos segundos han pasado desde que se modificó el fichero.

Así que puedes obtener lo que buscas así:

```
import time
from pathlib import Path

def minutos_desde_modificacion(f): 
    return (time.time() - f.stat().st_mtime)/60

dir_ = r"C:\Users\Jose Antonio\Documents"
ficheros_viejos = [f for f in Path(dir_).iterdir() if minutos_desde_modificacion(f)>10]
```

Obviamente para saber cuántos son basta con hacer `len(ficheros_viejos)`

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por responder, me devuelve lo siguiente: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jose Antonio\PycharmProjects\PrimerPrograma\venv\script.py", line 25, in <module>
    ficheros_viejos = [p for p in Path(r).iterdir() if minutos_desde_modificacion(p)>10]
NameError: name 'r' is not defined
`

Comment: Había un bug en mi respuesta, ya lo he editado (pero has copiado la versión anterior)

Comment: Funciona! Muchisimas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Los métodos `os.path.getctime` y `os.path.getmtime` te devuelven la fecha de creación y de modificación de un archivo en segundos epoch, por lo que puedes compararlo con la fecha actual y devolver los que superen los 10 minutos:

```
files = [_ for _ in os.listdir('.') if (time.time() - os.path.getctime(_)) / 60 >= 10 and os.path.isfile(_)]
```

Comment: Hola! Muchas gracias por responder!

Comment: El único <pero>, por asi decirlo, de usar `os.listdir()` es que también trae directorios, pero si el directorio de trabajo no tiene subdirectorios no debe haber problemas.

Comment: bien visto @aeportugal, corrijo y añado os.path.isfile para quitar los directorios